# Alternate URL crawled by google for app indexing is wrong

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

We have added the alternate link correctly in our webpage.
https://autoportal.com/newcars/bmw/5-series-gt/
`<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.autoportal.india/autoportal-android/autoportal.com/newcars/model/bmw-5-series-gt" />`

But when I checked the error mentioned my google in the webmaster console it shows the error `Removed from index: wrong URL`. This is coming because the APP URI which google parsed is
`android-app://com.autoportal.india/http/autoportal.com/newcars/bmw/m5/`.

[image]

There are a lot more similar errors.
It would be great if anyone could explain if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The same problem here. Looks like Google just construct App URL from Web URL using some internal rules (basically addition it right after app ID and separate protocol from the rest of URL by slash), **instead of** following rel="alternate".